# There exists a non-negative random variable such that $P( \{ \omega \in \Omega: E(X)-2\sigma<X(\omega)<E(X)+2\sigma \})=\frac{3}{5}$. True or False?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem**
State whether given statement is True or False.

> There exists a non-negative random variable such that:
>
> $P( \{ \omega \in \Omega: E(X)-2\sigma<X(\omega)<E(X)+2\sigma \})=\frac{3}{5}$

**My Approach**
If this random variable exists $E(X)-2\sigma<X(\omega)<E(X)+2\sigma$

$-2 < \frac{x-E(X)}{\sigma}<2$

What happens to the $\frac35$?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $\sigma$ here is the standard deviation of $X$. We have $P(|X-EX| \geq 2\sigma) \leq \frac {Var (x)} {4\sigma^{2}}=\frac 1  4$. Taking probability of the  complement w eget $P(-2\sigma <X-EX < 2\sigma) \geq 1- \frac  1 4=\frac   3 4$. Thusm=s, $P(EX-2\sigma <x< EX+2\sigma) \geq \frac 3  4$. But $\frac 3  4 >\frac  3 5$, so no such r.v. can exist.